# chef powershell cookbook, fail if node['ms_dotnet']['v4']['version'] < '4.5', where to set the node attribute

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I’m trying to use the chef [supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/powershell) to install powershell.

.NET version `4.52`  is installed on the node.

I run chef-client thusly:

```
$ chef-client –o "recipe[powershell::powershell4]"
```

The failure is:

```
fail 'Attribute ms_dotnet.v4.version is not configured to install .NET4.5 as required for Powershell4' if node['ms_dotnet']['v4']['version'] < '4.5'
```

This error is from [line 32 in the powershell4.rb](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/powershell/blob/v3.2.3/recipes/powershell4.rb#L32) recipe.

Where do you suppose I'm supposed to set the node attribute `node['ms_dotnet']['v4']['version']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best response I heard was:

Create a **wrapper cookbook** and set the node property in there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the recipe is just not written correctly. Guessing most people are installing PS5 and no one has noticed.